# How to set the inputType for a TextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'd like to restrict what the user can type in a TextField in Jetpack Compose. How do I do that?

The equivalent in xml is `inputType`:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="Only numbers please!" />
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use [KeyboardOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/KeyboardOptions#KeyboardOptions(androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardCapitalization,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction)):

```
TextField(
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
```

Comment: if {,.-} are not necessary (keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword) can be used

Comment: If `.` is necessary use `KeyboardType.Decimal` as `Number` doesn't guarantee it

Answer (score 7):

Ty like this [KeyboardOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/KeyboardOptions#KeyboardOptions(androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardCapitalization,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction))

```
var textShopName by remember { mutableStateOf("") } 

OutlinedTextField(
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
                autoCorrect = true,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            value = textShopName,
            onValueChange = { textShopName = it },
            label = { Text("Shop Name") },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 20.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),

            )
```

Answer (score 4):

For **Password** keyboard type for hiding password you have to set the `visualTransformation` too

```
TextField(
 keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
 visualTransformation =  PasswordVisualTransformation(),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
TextField(
        ....,
        keyboardOptions = 
             KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
```

Comment: What's the advantage of copying the default?

Comment: @Sergey The advantage is to override only a single value.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the answers above if you want to show **numeric keyboard for decimal numbers** keep in mind that:

*Most keyboards show a decimal separator when keyboard type is set as Number.* **However**, it is possible that a keyboard expects `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` flag in inputType to actually show a key for decimal separator.

So if you want to show numeric keyboard for decimal numbers in order to avoid corner cases in certain keyboards you should use `keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal`:

```
TextField(
        ...,
        keyboardOptions = 
             KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal)
        ...,    
        )
```

Comment: Inside the Code found `androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType`
"A keyboard type used to request an IME that is capable of inputting decimals. IME should explicitly provide a decimal separator as input, which is not assured by KeyboardType.Number."