# Phone keyboard doesn't popup when I click on TextField Compose in DialogFragment

Tags: android, textfield, dialogfragment

Below is the code for custom TextField. I have used TextField in Fragment and DialogFragment. I am having some issues while using it in DialogFragment. The phone keyboard opens when I click on the TextField below when it is used in Fragment. But even though it focuses on the TextField, the keyboard doesn't pop up when it is used in DialogFragment.

```
fun MyTextFiled(
    search: (String) -> Unit,
    query: String?
) {
    var state by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(query) }
    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_5dp)),
    ) {
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.height(36.dp).background(colorResource(id = R.color.background_wallet_searchView)),
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_new_search),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(20.dp)
                    .padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_5dp)),
                tint = colorResource(id = R.color.text_secondary),
            )
            BasicTextField(
                value = state?:"",
                onValueChange = {
                    search.invoke(it)
                    state = it
                },
                maxLines = 1,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1F)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_5dp)),
                singleLine = true,
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.text_secondary),
                    fontSize = 13.sp,
                    fontStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.overline.fontStyle
                ),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                    capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences,
                    autoCorrect = true,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Search
                ),
                decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                    if (state.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.search),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.overline,
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                            color = colorResource(id = R.color.text_secondary)
                        )
                    }
                    innerTextField()
                }
            )
            if (!state.isNullOrEmpty())
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.round_close_24),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            state = ""
                            search.invoke("")
                        }
                        .size(20.dp)
                        .padding(end = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_5dp))
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use keyboardOptions like this link does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482474/13083841

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in compose 1.4.0 alpha. However, the keyboard pops up under the `DialogFragment` such that keypresses are not detected!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. I used Dialog Compose inside Dialog Fragment and the keyboard popped up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So what do you return in `onCreateDialog`? Surely not a non-compose `Dialog`?

Comment: Here you can find possible workaround (BottomSheetDialogFragment can be replaced with DialogFragment): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262140644#comment7

Answer (score -1):

**MessageScreen:**

```
@Composable
fun MessageScreen(
    messagesViewModel: MessagesViewModel,
    navHostController: NavController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    // Set State of Message Screen
    val receiverProfile = sharedViewModel.receiverProfile
    val senderProfile = sharedViewModel.senderProfile
    Log.d("TAG", "MessageScreen: RECEIVER = $receiverProfile  SENDER = $senderProfile")

    // Get All Messages from Firebase
    messagesViewModel.getAllMessageFromFirebase(receiverProfile, senderProfile)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    ) {

        TopBar(
            title = receiverProfile!!.displayName,
            buttonIcon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_back_arrow_back_24)
        ) {
            navHostController.popBackStack()
        }

        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(10f)) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                state = listState
            ) {

                items(items = messagesViewModel.allMessagesState) { message ->

                    MessageCard(message = message, sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel)
                    Log.d("TAG 14", message.toString())
                }
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    if (messagesViewModel.allMessagesState.isNotEmpty()) {
                        listState.scrollToItem(messagesViewModel.allMessagesState.size - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(8.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            SendMessageCard(messagesViewModel, sharedViewModel)
        }

    }
}
`

**SendMessageCard :-**
@Composable
fun SendMessageCard(messagesViewModel: MessagesViewModel, sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel) {

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        elevation = 8.dp
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = messagesViewModel.textState.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    messagesViewModel.textState.value = it
                },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),

                trailingIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                            messagesViewModel.sendMessage(
                                message = Message(
                                    messagesViewModel.textState.value,
                                    Timestamp.now(),
                                    sharedViewModel.senderProfile!!.mailId
                                ),
                                sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
                            )
                    }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Send, contentDescription = "Send Message")
                    }
                },
                textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp),
                label = {
                    Text(text = "Type Message")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation, not meta-commentary

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).